# python flask ImmutableMultiDict

Tags: python, forms, flask

This is my code:

```
@user_bp.route('/band', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def band_details():
    from include.form.User import Banddetails
    form = Banddetails()

    if request.method == 'POST' and  form.validate_on_submit():

         pippo =  request.args.getlist('name[]')
         print 'sei passato di qui' + str(len(pippo))
         for item in pippo:
             print item      
         return "result"        
    return render_template("banddetails.html", form=form, session=session)
```

I have a similar form:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" value="">
```

I want get the element `name[]`, `lastname[]`, ... but I don't understand the procedure described in the flask api.

Comment: Where in documentation is the "procedure" you are referring to?  Can you point to the part of the docs you find confusing?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you are using an HTTP POST method you need to retrieve parameters like this:

```
 pippo =  request.form.getlist('name[]')
```

If you use HTTP GET method, do it like this:

```
 pippo =  request.args.getlist('name[]')
```

Check the docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data).

Comment: at the moment I can't vote because my reputation is not enough, when my reputation is enough I vote  ;)

Comment: For me, this works: request.form.getlist('name') - the '[]' does not work.

Comment: @rjurney yes its depends on name of input tag you provided. in actual qus he used `name[]`

Comment: ugh.  spent hours trying to figure out why post data from jquery wasn't showing up in request.json like all the other examples I've seen out there.  finally found this when searching for ImmutableMultiDict.  I hate flask so much.

Comment: This helps me as well by replacing the name with actual parameter name

Answer (score 43):

you can do the following

```
d = request.form.to_dict()
```

or, if you're expecting an array of params

```
d = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
```

sources:
[immutable multi-dict doc](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.html)
[to_dict doc](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.to_dict.html#werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.to_dict)

Comment: This method can not be used when we expect array of params, look `getlist -> ImmutableMultiDict([('test', 'a'), ('test, 'b')])` and `to_dict -> {'test': 'a'}`, we have lost other params.

Comment: This solution is very *DANGEROUS* if the `<input>` allows [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefmultiple) values, as was mentioned by @MrHIDEn!

Comment: Good point. See updated answer.

Comment: if you are uploading files just change it to request.files.to_dict()