# how to access checked rows from a table data

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html

i have a dynamically generated table and after the table loads i need to print few selected rows in console based on checkbox.

The table is populated with data from backend.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left : 8px !important;margin-right : 8px !important">
                    <table class="table table-bordered fixed_headers" id="Device_list">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                <th>IPADDRESS</th>
                                <th>DEVICE NAME</th>
                                <th>STATUS</th>
                                <th>BACKUP</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id = "all_device">
                            {% for item in Device_list %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="device_check"/></td>
                                        <td>{{ item['ipaddress'] }} </td>
                                        <td>{{ item['name'] }} </td>
                                        <td>{{ item['status'] }} </td>
                                        {% if item['backup'] == 'no_backup' %}
                                            <td>{{ item['backup'] }}</td>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <td><a href="{{ url_for('backups_texts',path = item['backup']) }}">Backup</a> </td>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                        <input type="submit" id="bt" value="Show Table Data"  />
                    </table>

function myfunc() {
        console.log ("inside my function");
        var valuelist = [];
        $('#all_device tr').each(function() {
            $(this).find("input[name='device_check']:checked").each(function() {
                var values = [];
                $(this).closest("td").siblings("td").each(function() {
                    values.push($(this).text());
                });
                valuelist.push(values.join(", "));
            });
        });
        console.log("(" + valuelist.join("),(") + ")");
   }
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bt").click(function() {
            myfunc();
        });
   });
```

Kindly help with accessing the table row content.

Comment: Doesn't your code (`myfunc`) work?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code doesn't work but it would be better to query all checked checkboxes instead of looping through all `tr`, like this:

```
function myfunc() {
    var valuelist = [];
    $('#all_device input[name=device_check]:checked').each(function(i, c){
        var cb = $(c);
        valuelist.push(cb.parent().siblings().map(function(si, s){ return $(s).text() }).get());
    });

  console.log('Selected', valuelist);
}
```

The console should output like so:

[image: Console output]

*Note: Screenshot only shows sample data*

**EDIT**

If you want to follow your original code (where valuelist is an array of comma-separated values, you can use this code instead:

```
function myfunc() {
    var valuelist = [];
    $('#all_device input[name=device_check]:checked').each(function(i, c){
        var cb = $(c);
        valuelist.push(cb.parent().siblings().map(function(si, s){ return $(s).text() }).get().join(', '));
    });

  console.log('Selected', '(' + valuelist.join('),(') + ')');
}
```

Comment: HI, @dunli thanks for the comment i got the preferred output on the console but then i am stuck with access of this list at the backend which i am sending through ajax call . request.form on the python side gives ImmutableMultiDict. any idea how to access this in python function .Thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: ajax call --- $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/backup',
            data: JSON.stringify(valuelist),
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.value);
            }
        });

Comment: @app.route('/backup', methods=['POST',"GET"])
def backup_conf():
    if request.method == "POST":
        value = request.form()
 print (value)
 return ""

Comment: getting output as : ImmutableMultiDict([('[["10.11.9.3","host1","Node status is Up","no_backup"],["10.11.9.4","host2","Node status is Up","no_backup"]]', '')])

Comment: Hi, I'm don't really know how to code python, but try these links: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205577/python-flask-immutablemultidict
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176594/passing-list-of-values-to-django-view-via-jquery-ajax-call
https://healeycodes.com/javascript/python/beginners/webdev/2019/04/11/talking-between-languages.html