# Select element option value not showing in js

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I'm working on dependent dropdown box with https://tutorial101.blogspot.com/2021/01/python-flask-dynamic-loading-of.html as a reference but with ibm_db.

The idea is when an particular option is selected in the first dropdown box, related options are displayed in second dropdown box.

When I'm selecting an option in first box, second box is not being displayed because the parent id from first box is not going to the second box.

In flask.py second route parent_id is supposed to be populated.

```
@app.route("/unplanned_outage", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def unplanned_outage():
    cur1 = conn.cursor()
    select="select * from impacted_tools"
    cur1.execute(select)
    tools = cur1.fetchall()
    cur1.close()
    return render_template(r'unplannedoutage.html', tools=tools)

@app.route("/get_servers_list", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_servers_list():
    cur2 = conn.cursor()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        parent_id = request.form['parent_id']
        print(parent_id)
        cur2.execute("select * from impacted_servers where tools_id = %s", [parent_id])
        servers = cur2.fetchall()
        return jsonify({'htmlresponse': render_template('response.html', servers=servers)})
```

first_box.html

search_category_id from select element is not picking option value row[0] and hence I'm getting undefined for console.log($('#search_category_id').val()). Hence its not going to get_servers_list route.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script> 
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home Page</title>

    <script> 
    console.log($('#search_category_id').val());
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search_category_id').change(function(){
            $.post("/get_servers_list", {
                parent_id: $('#search_category_id').val(),
            }, function(response){ 
                $('#show_sub_categories').html(response);
                $('#show_sub_categories').append(response.htmlresponse);
            });
    return false;
  });
}); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form-id" class="row g-3" style="margin: auto; width: 80%;  padding: 30px;" onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label for="search_category_id" class="form-label">Impacted Tools</label>
            <select name="search_category"  id="search_category_id" class="form-control form-select js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Tools">
              <option value="" selected></option>
              {% for row in tools %}
              <option value='{{row[0]}}'>{{row[1]}}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div id="show_sub_categories"></div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label for="inputState3" class="form-label">Expected Output</label>
            <select id="inputState3" class="form-select">
              <option selected></option>
              <option>RTC</option>
            </select>
          </div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Validate</button>
        </div>
      </form>
</body>
```

response.html
I pasted the same header in this just in case.

```
<body>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <label for="sub_category_id" class="form-label">Impacted Services</label>
        <select name="sub_category"  id="sub_category_id" class="form-control">
          <option value="" selected></option>
          {% for row in servers %} 
          <option value="{{row[0]}}">{{row[2]}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
</body>
```

Please help me on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Put the `console.log()` call inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Barmar i have done as you said  `$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('#search_category_id').val())
 });`
the result in console is ->
`
['']

0: ""
length: 1`

Comment: Of course. It's running before the user has selected anything from the menu.

Comment: If you want to see the user's selection, put it inside the `.change()` function.

Comment: You probably shouldn't do the submission in the `change` event of a multi-select. You should wait until the user has made all the selections and use a submit button.

Comment: @Barmar   yea.. you're right. i changed to this:
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search_category_id').change(function(){
  console.log($('#search_category_id').val())
 });
 });`
and the result is showing as

(2) ['', '2']
0: ""
1: "2"
length: 2
i selected the second option

Comment: Multi-select doesn't usually need a default option. You need to deselect it to remove it from the array.

Comment: @Barmar i removed it. Im getting ['1', '2']. I suppose parent_id needs to be a list in my case?

Comment: Yes. Flask will automatically convert multiple parameters into a list.

Comment: jQuery will add `[]` to the parameter name when the value is an array. I'm not sure if Flask removes these automatically. If not, try `parent_id = request.form['parent_id[]')`

Comment: @Barmar ive added it, no change. Im getting POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_servers_list 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) when selecting an option. the parent id is not being sent to the server.

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check the server's error log to see what error Python got.

Comment: What does `print(request.form)` show?

Comment: @Barmar print(request.form) gives - ImmutableMultiDict([('parent_id[]', '2')])
i used exception block to catch the error, it says - Error: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: @Barmar when i give multi select its giving ImmutableMultiDict([('parent_id[]', '1'), ('parent_id[]', '2')])

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205577/python-flask-immutablemultidict

Comment: @Barmar thank you! i tried d = request.form.to_dict(flat=False) from the link and i got it in the form of a dictionary like {'parent_id[]': ['1', '2']}. I got the dict values and im using it further to give to my sql query. Thank you so much for guiding me!